# Loop through an element in the foreach loop and extract the acronym from the value and then set another element's value to the derived acronym

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having this challenge of looping through an element in a foreach iteration and then extract an acronym from the element, then set another element's value to the derived acronym.

Here's my code

**1) cshtml:**

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{                
     <h3 class="getName">@item.FullName</h3>
     [...]
     <h4 class="displayAvatar"></h4>
     [...]
}
```

**2) Jquery code:**

```
$('.getName').each(function (e) {
        var techieFullName = $('.getName').text();
        var getNameAcronym = techieFullName.match(/\b(\w)/g);
        var theName = getNameAcronym.join('');
        $('.displayAvatar').text(theName);
});
```

The code above assigns the same result(derived acronym) to all h4 elements with class of "displayAvatar" but i want each fullname  be set to each acronym

**How do i get it running please? Appreciate**

Comment: `var techieFullName = $(this).text();` and then you need a relative selector to get the associated `<h4>` element. e.g. wrap each iteration in a `<div class="container>` and `$(this).closest('.container').find(.displayAvatar).text(theName);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks. Just did but it's still same but when  i commented  out  $(this).closest('.container').find(.displayAvatar).text(theN‌​ame);  the acronym found for the last iteration is returned to all displayavatar classes. What do i need to do?

Comment: Then clearly you did not do it correctly - `foreach(..){<div class="container"><h3 class="getName">@item.FullName</h3><h4 class="displayAvatar"></h4></div>}`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks. It's good now. Appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the immediately following sibling with class `displayAvatar`:

```
$('.getName').each(function (e) {
    var techieFullName = $(this).text();
    var getNameAcronym = techieFullName.match(/\b(\w)/g);
    var theName = getNameAcronym.join('');
    $(this).next(".displayAvatar").text(theName);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your using a `forEach` Loop. Its easier if you enclose multiple heading tags inside a `div` say `eachRow`. script is provided below, its straight forward.

**CSHTML:**

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{     
   <div class="eachRow">           
     <h3 class="getName">@item.FullName</h3>
     <h4 class="displayAvatar"></h4>
   </div>
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.getName').each(function (e) {
        var techieFullName = $(this).text();
        var getNameAcronym = techieFullName.match(/\b(\w)/g);
        var theName = getNameAcronym.join('');
        $(this).closest('.eachRow').find('.displayAvatar').text(theName);
});
```

**Edit:** 
Use pipe lining to reduce the use of many local variables.

```
$('.getName').each(function (e) {
            var result=  $(this).text().match(/\b(\w)/g).join('');
            $(this).closest('.eachRow').find('.displayAvatar').text(result);
    });
```